# How to disable a button using Element.io after its clicked?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a button using Element.io and I want the button to disable once its clicked because it only should be clicked once. Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is what my code for the button looks like:

```
<div>
      <el-button type="primary" @click="handleOnClick">Update Graphs</el-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the context is, but if you use a normal html button, you can achieve this very easily with `onclick="this.disabled=true"` inside of the button declaration. For example,

```html
<div>
      <button type="primary" onclick="this.disabled=true">Update Graphs</button>
</div>
```